# Discord.py Cog cannot take in content param

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm in discord.py right now, and whenever I directly edit bot.py (my main file) I can implement a version of my suggest command.

```
@bot.command(name = 'suggest', help = 'Use this command to give a suggestion to the server')
async def suggest(ctx, content):
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].channels, name = 'suggestions')
    print('Suggest command triggered, content is {}'.format(content))
    await channel.send(content)
```

^ bot is just my version of client

This works perfectly fine (except the fact that I only get the 1st word of content, so if someone could solve that, that would also be nice

But when I copy paste into my cog

```
    @commands.command(name = 'suggest', help = 'Use this command to give a suggestion to the server')
    async def suggest(self, bot, ctx, content):
        print('Suggest command triggered')
        channel = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].channels, name = 'suggestions')
        print('Content is {}'.format(content))
        await channel.send(content)
```

It **doesn't work**, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For a cog, that `bot` parameter is unnecessary, so you just put

```
    @commands.command(name = 'suggest', help = 'Use this command to give a suggestion to the server')
    async def suggest(self, ctx, content):
        print('Suggest command triggered')
        channel = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds[0].channels, name = 'suggestions')
        print('Content is {}'.format(content))
        await channel.send(content)
```

As for the only having the first word, discord.py separates arguments by words, so you can just group them all with a `*` like so:

```
    async def suggest(self, ctx, *content):  # gets all the words in a tuple
```